# Does anyone have experience of using jsf4birt under JBoss 6?

Tags: jsf, birt, jboss6.x

I would like to use jsf4birt to put birt report into xhtml pages. I tried to deploy exadel-jsf4birt-demo.war under jboss 6 but failed. Max@exadel said that jsf4birt only suppourts JSF 1.2, so does anyone have experience of using jsf4birt under JBoss 6? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. There is a bug in jsf4bir's tag definition file jsfbirt.tld:

```
    <attribute>
        <description>Defines UI Option name</description>
        <name>name</name>
        <deferred-value>
            <type>java.lang.String</type>
        </deferred-value>
        <required>true</required>
    </attribute>
```

this should be:

```
    <attribute>
        <description>Defines UI Option name</description>
        <name>name</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <deferred-value>
            <type>java.lang.String</type>
        </deferred-value>           
    </attribute>
```